# Laravel repository pattern query building

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have made repository to get records from database. Everything is working but I want to add `orderBy` method if there is variable in session:

So far I have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserRepository
{
    protected $user;
    private   $columns;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user    = $user;
        $this->columns = ['id', 'email', 'pwd', 'name', 'addr', 'addr_detail', 'addr_no', 'city', 'zip', 'state', 'phone', 'company_number', 'vat_id', 'tax_id', 'unique_string', 'active', 'banned', 'admin'];
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        if (Session::has('sort')) 
        {
            $sort = Session::get('sort');
            if (isset($sort["users"]) && !empty($sort["users"]))
                $this->user->orderBy($sort['users']['column'], $sort['users']['type']);
        }

        return $this->user->select($this->columns)->withCount([
            'orders',
            'orders as turnover' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(price) as turnover")); },
            'orders as profit'   => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(profit) as profit")); },
            ])->get();
    }
}
```

The condition returns true but the records are not sorted by it. I even tried to put `$this->user->orderBy()` before return but it wasnt sorded at all. It appears it isnt used at all.

Here is the query it runs:

```
"select `id`, `email`, `pwd`, `name`, `addr`, `addr_detail`, `addr_no`, `city`, `zip`, `state`, `phone`, `company_number`, `vat_id`, `tax_id`, `unique_string`, `active`, `banned`, `admin`, (select count(*) from `orders` where `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`) as `orders_count`, (select SUM(price) as turnover from `orders` where `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`) as `turnover`, (select SUM(profit) as profit from `orders` where `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id`) as `profit` from `users` "
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you sure the `orderBy()` is executed? or try to put it after the primary query.

Comment: I cant call it after return. If I chain in before ->get() in hardcore like orderBy(‘id’) it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->user->select($this->columns)->withCount([
            'orders',
            'orders as turnover' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(price) as turnover")); },
            'orders as profit'   => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(profit) as profit")); },
            ]);

        if (Session::has('sort')) 
        {
            $sort = Session::get('sort');
            if (isset($sort["users"]) && !empty($sort["users"]))
                $query = $query->orderBy($sort['users']['column'], $sort['users']['type']);
        }

        return $query->get();
    }
```

Be sure your `if (isset($sort["users"]) && !empty($sort["users"]))` let the execution in.

Comment: The conditions are true it was the first thing I tried. And I have this in repository not in controller I dont have access to $request

Comment: Oh I see. I am out of my pc will try first thing tomorrow. Thanks hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it seems the orderBy is not reflecting to next query at the select..

```
public function getAll()
{
        $query = $this->user;
        if (Session::has('sort')) 
        {
            $sort = Session::get('sort');
            if (isset($sort["users"]) && !empty($sort["users"])) {
                $query = $query->orderBy($sort['users']['column'], $sort['users']['type']);
            }
        }

        return $query->select($this->columns)->withCount([
            'orders',
            'orders as turnover' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(price) as turnover")); },
            'orders as profit'   => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(profit) as profit")); },
            ])->get();
    }
```

Comment: not working :( I added also query it runs to my question and there is no order by